# Stateful Containers with Kubernetes/Docker is it possible?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I apologize if this is an ignorant question but I am building out a Kubernetes cluster and I really like the idea of abstracting my computing infrastructure from a single cloud provider and steering away from a VM platform but what about statefulness? I want to be able to setup a mysql server for example and keep that data for life, I want Kubernetes to load balance a mysql container with a data drive, we speak about containers and we think life and death within seconds but what about when we want to keep data around and build a kick ass data center without VM's is there a concept of of being stateful in this paradigm?

Comment: Take a look at Persistent Volumes and Persistent Volume Claims.

Comment: The official [Kubernetes tutorials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/) include three examples of stateful applications, including a WordPress/MySQL setup.  I think it's also pretty common to use a cloud-managed database or otherwise run your persistent storage outside of Kubernetes, and use Kubernetes for your actual application with stateless containers; it doesn't have to be all-or-nothing.

Comment: Thanks David and Burak the tutorial links were very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not ignorant at all, in fact, stateful apps (often DBs) require special consideration in Kubernetes.

[StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) are one of the primary Kubernetes objects that exist to help support the use of stateful apps.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/stateful-apps#overview) is a decent guide to solving some of the challenges. It's written by Google for Kubernetes Engine but the concepts apply to Kubernetes broadly.  There is also a [GKE-specific overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/statefulset).

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes provides StatefulSets for Deploying stateful containers like databases. Follow the below link to understand how to deploy mysql database In highly available mode
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/